# Can i use decrative tile board in my shower?

Tags: bathroom

I am putting in a new tub and i had to take down the inside wall too replace some rotten studs.I am go'ing to put cement board on the wall.So can i put 1/8" tile board over the cement board for the final touch it claims to be water resestant? The brand name of this tile board is Decrative international.

Comment: If you prefer sheet material, consider synthetic countertop surfaces like corian. Most of the companies sell in dimensions suitable for shower enclosures. Other options could include sheet metal (industrial looking) or glass (backpainted is nice).

Comment: @DA01 - I saw a cool ass tub a few weeks ago that was three huge glass (or really clear thick plastic) panels.  They put all of the electric in metal tubing and made all of the plumbing look like art.  They then painted the studs a green and the back of the drywall black... not sure it was code but it was really cool and looked waterproof and easy.  Just shows we do keep doing things one way and I am sure there are easier alternatives coming.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can.  This is normal for bathtubs.  However note that there are tons of different grades of tile board, ranging from touch it with a watch and it scratched to some commercial grade boards that are pretty resistant.  I have no idea what quality yours is so just note that the coating and material itself (what material and thickness) is way more important than how it looks in some picture on a website.

Answer (score 0):

Can you? Sure. Will it work like tile? Will it wear like tile? Not in a million years.

IMPE, tileboard is a waste of time...and money, but not very much money, which is what suckers people into trying it. It's cheap, it will soon look like what it cost, and you'll probably regret it. Inexpensive actual tile is a much better option.